# How do I limit input rate using max record count on Structured Streaming in Databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

I'm trying to limit the input rate for a Structured Streaming query using a maximum record count.
However, the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/structured-streaming/batch-size.html) says only `maxFilesPerTrigger` or `maxBytesPerTrigger` are supported.

Are there any workarounds to achieving this with a maximum record count?

Please Advise

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not explicitly mentioned, I suppose is that the question about Delta Lake streaming. Unfortunately, there is no support for maximum rows limit in Delta Lake, so you need to select for example some value for `maxBytesPerTrigger` that will approximately match the desired number of records that you want to process.

Partially (not 100% sure about reasoning), this could be caused by the fact that Delta is file-based format where it's harder to control number of records compared to message-oriented services like Kafka.

P.S. it looks like there is such option in Delta Live Tables

P. P.S. Why do you need to limit number of records per batch?

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a shot. Just exploring options since I found a `.option("maxRecordsPerTrigger", 10000)` option

Comment: where did you find it?

Comment: Found it [here](https://www.qiniu.com/qfans/qnso-69665937) barely any documentation on it. But looks like it gets the job done

Comment: usually if it's not documented, then it could be experimental, so may change in the future.